# Unable to redirect after login in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to set up a redirection after log in but it doesn't seems to work even if the url changes, can someone help me?

--action--

```
SignIn : (context,payload)=>{
        axios.post('https:url',{email:payload.email,password:payload.password,returnSecureToken:true})
          .then(res => {context.commit('userAuth',res.data);
          console.log('Signed in',res);
         }).then(res => router.replace(''))
      }
```

--mutation

```
 userAuth(state,payload){
      state.idToken=payload.idToken;
      state.userId=payload.localId;
      state.expirationSession=payload.expiresIn+Date.now()*1000;
      console.log('Authentificated');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Router redirect with `''` path should not work, since it is not a valid path.

In case you want to redirect user to homepage (root of the app), `/` should be used as a path.

```
router.replace('/')
```

or

```
router.replace({
  path: '/'
})
```